# Inverse of matrix mod $26$ wolframalpha wrong

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic, inverse

I want to find $A^{-1} \pmod{26}$ for

$A=\begin{bmatrix}10&3\\5&3\end{bmatrix}$

and I did the conventional $\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}$ and found the inverse of the fraction mod $26$, cool, then reduced mod $26$ the matrix.

I obtained:

$$\begin{bmatrix}21&5\\17&18\end{bmatrix}$$

Cool - but the wolframalpha calculator [obtained the transpose of above](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=e157b43abc7b26438d6d67497a786743)? What the?

Who is right?

Comment: sometimes WA treats rows/columns in a way that is not clear, leading often to transpose issues if not dealt with properly

Comment: You are right, wolfram alpha is wrong!

Comment: Trying both answers shows yours is right, and the transpose doesn't work.

Comment: Yay. Silly wolfram alpha :). Smart humans!

Comment: Strangely enough, "Inverse[{{10,3},{5,3}},Modulus->26]" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful that Wolfram addresses your $a,b,c,d$ to $1,2,3,4$, so you should have written your $a,b,c,d$  in the corresponding order to the entries $1,2,3,4$, which gives the matrix $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
       c & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
It is not handy, but that is how this beta widget works.

[image: See this;]

Comment: Oh yes I see, so it was silly humans afterall :P [the programmers]